# Gradle build generated variable instead of string value

Tags: android, gradle

I added this code to my build.gradle module: app in android{} section.

```
 buildTypes.each 
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "f4a8ad01f485a8276a6dbc4d364b"
}
```

But it's causing error

> Error:(14, 57) error: cannot find symbol variable
>   f4a8ad01f485a8276a6dbc4d364b

The OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY value isn't generated inside of ""

```
public final class BuildConfig {
     public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
     public static final String APPLICATION_ID ="com.example.weatherforecast";
     public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
     public static final String FLAVOR = "";
     public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
     public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
     // Fields from build type: debug
     public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = f4a8ad01f485a8276a6dbc4d364b;
}
```

In class FetchWeatherTask.java I have this line of code, and it doesn't show any errors.

```
private final String APP_ID = BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY;
```

Why in `BuildConfig.java OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY` value it's generated as variable instead of String value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to quote it:

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', '"f4a8ad01f485a8276a6dbc4d364b"'
```